# Ordering a nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, django

I have a nested dictionary (category and subcategories), `dict`, that I am having trouble sorting.

The output of `dict` is:

```
{u'sports': {u'basketball': {'name': u'Basketball', 'slug': u'basketball'}, u'baseball': {'name': u'Baseball', 'slug': u'baseball'}}, u'dance': {u'salsa': {'name': u'Salsa', 'slug': u'salsa'}}, u'arts': {u'other-5': {'name': u'Other', 'slug': u'other-5'}, u'painting': {'name': u'Painting', 'slug': u'painting'}}, u'music': {u'cello': {'name': u'Cello', 'slug': u'cello'}, u'accordion': {'name': u'Accordion', 'slug': u'accordion'}}}
```

How can I sort this dictionary so that the 'other' subcategory always shows up at the end of the nested dictionary. For example the order for the "arts" category should be:

```
..., u'arts': {u'painting': {'name': u'Painting', 'slug': u'painting'}, u'other-5': {'name': u'Other', 'slug': u'other-5'}}...
```

Comment: an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) might be useful for you

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want the categories to be ordered? Python `dict`s are inherently unordered, but there is the `OrderedDict` which remembers the order the keys were added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python dictionaries (regular `dict` instances) are not sorted. If you want to sort your dict, you could:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

mynewdict = OrderedDict(sorted(yourdict.items()))
```

An OrderedDict does not provide a sorting mechanism, but only respect the order of the keys being inserted on it (we sort those keys calling sorted beforehand).

Since you need a specific criteria (lets say your keys are alphabetically ordered except for the "other" key which goes to the end), you need to declare it:

```
def mycustomsort(key):
    return (0 if key != 'other' else 1, key)
mynewdict = OrderedDict(sorted(yourdict.items(), key=mycustomsort))
```

This way you are creating a tuple for the nested criteria: the first criteria is other vs. no-other, and so the 0 or 1 (since 1 is greater, other comes later), while the second criteria is the key itself. You can remove the second criteria and not return a tuple if you want, but only the 0 and 1, and the code will work without alphabetical sort.

**This solution will not work** if you plan to edit the dictionary later, and there is no standard class supporting that.

Comment: Thanks for providing a complete solution! This worked perfectly for my use case.

Comment: Actually this doesn't move Other to the end, it just sorts alphabetically.

Comment: Function corrected to: def mycustomsort(key):
    return (0 if 'other' not in key else 1, key)

Answer (score 3):

You have some major concept misunderstanding about dictionary. Dictionary in python is like a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), hash table has no order. The output of the dict is really environment dependent so you couldn't depend on that. You might see one way of the output while other people see another way. You should consider using [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead.

Comment: So you're saying there's no way to accomplish this?

Comment: If you want order, you shouldn't be even using `dict`. You can get away with it using `OrderedDict`, but I feel like using tuple of tuples would make more sense.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. Why do you recommend tuples over an OrderedDict?

Comment: `OrderedDict` is not available in all python versions, and tuple is immutable so it's faster and definitely preserves the sequence, unless you need the O(1) access time from `dict`, in which case you would use `OrderedDict`.